# Tracing the path of a pendulum in animation

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am making an animation of a double pendulum and I would like to trace the path of the second pendulum only, to show the chaotic motion. I have included the code I have so far for the animation. It runs and both pendulums move smoothly, but I feel that a solid line tracing the path of the second bob would add to the demonstration.

```
def animate(i):
    ln1.set_data([0, x1[i], x2[i]], [0, y1[i], y2[i]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize = (8,8))
ln1, = plt.plot([], [], '-', lw=2, markersize=8)
ax.set_ylim(-4,4)
ax.set_xlim(-4,4)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000, interval=10)
ani.save('Double Pendulum.gif', writer = "Pillow", fps = 25)
```

I tried adding a line to the code block to plot the position of the second pendulum, but it made a separate graph instead of tracing the path.`your text`